# Jenkin process firewall: autovacuum reader 100% cpu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, firewall

I am a newbie in Jenkins. After setup and run Jenkins on an Ubuntu server, I have tried to install some plugins and make a pipeline for building and deploying images to Kubernetes. I got an error "refused to connect" when access the Jenkin website port 8080. I have checked my ubuntu server and realized that there are 2 processes make 100% CPU like the below screenshot.
[Jenkin process firewall: autovacuum reader 100% cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2892.png)
I have tried restarted Jenkins service as well as killed the processes but after restarting, the issue still happens

How do I resolve it?
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with this issue. I couldn't find any solution. This solution is not the best way but it worked for me. In my case, the CPU became very stable around 1-2%.
I created a script that stopped the firewall process and I registered it in crontab.

```
@reboot /root/kill-firewall.sh > /root/kill-firewall.log
```

kill-firewall.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    kill -9 `ps -ef | grep jenkins | grep firewall | awk '{print $2}'` || true
    sleep 5
done
```